# Numpy error: underflow encountered in exp

Tags: python, numpy, error-handling, floating-point

I'm attempting to define a simple exponential and regardless of the numbers I put into the argument of the exponential I get the following:

`FloatingPointError: underflow encountered in exp`

The array I'm trying to define is as follows:

```
     time = np.arange(length)
     window = np.exp(-(time-512)**2/1000.0)
```

where `length = 4096`.  I'm rather inexperienced with Python and saw a similar question was answered on here somewhere but I didn't really understand it.  I should also note that this code ran before without a problem.

Comment: Are you sure you don't want `1000**2` rather than `1000`? The factor of `1000` looks rather unlikely, given the size of values you're working with.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Break down what you're computing for the final element:

```
temp1 = 4096 - 512
temp2 = temp1**2
temp3 = -temp2
temp4 = temp3 / 1000.0
```

temp4 is -12845.056

Now, what happens when you try to take the natural anti-log of that number?  What is the range of float values you're allowed in numpy?

I believe you'll find that you just tried to make it too small.  If this is an intermediate result in a computation, I suggest that you hold the number as a natural log until you can make it larger again.  Alternately, research some packages to support extreme values, or multiply all your values by a scalar large enough to preserve accuracy.

Comment: Thanks!  I'm confused because the code runs without any error messages in one folder, but I have a copy of the notebook in a parent directory.  The one in the parent directory gives me issues.  I've tried the copy in the folder both before and after posting this question and it works just fine.  Do you know why this would be the case?

Comment: No idea.  Try sticking in a couple of print statements to report `length` and track the creation.  Can you manually curtail `length` to check basic operation?

Comment: e^-12845.056 = 2.9...e-5579. That underflows a double and even an extended precision (80 bit) floating point type.